# Connecting to network with wifi shield

Tags: arduino-uno, shields, wifi

I just bought a WiFi shield and I cannot connect to my wireless network (WPA2).

- I used the [sketch from the Arduino site](http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/ConnectWithWPA) for connecting to WPA network and put my SSID and password on but it doesn't connect (I know the credentials are correct as I used my phone to connect with these WiFi credentials).
- When I read the serial monitor it just keeps trying to connect. The WiFi-shield board error light is red
- I checked my network settings and my block level is at is lowest (NAT only).

**Why can't I connect?**

Answer (score 1):

In the loop:

```
// attempt to connect to Wifi network:
  while ( status != WL_CONNECTED) { 
    Serial.print("Attempting to connect to WPA SSID: ");
    Serial.println(ssid);
    // Connect to WPA/WPA2 network:    
    status = WiFi.begin(ssid, pass);

    // wait 10 seconds for connection:
    delay(10000);
  }
```

Can you add `Serial.print(status);` before the delay so you can see if any of these arise:

- WL_IDLE_STATUS = 0
- WL_NO_SSID_AVAIL
- WL_CONNECT_FAILED
- WL_CONNECTION_LOST
- WL_DISCONNECTED

They are defined in `wl_definitions.h`

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue using the Feather M0 board from Adafruit. After updating the Arduino IDE as well as the IDE's libraries and firmware, I was able to connect to WiFi.